# Elasticsearch: Slow fuzzy_like_this queries

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an ES cluster with 2 servers, each holding 5 shards of an index. (5 shards / 1 replica)
The index contains 50 Mio. documents containing product data, which results in 70GB database size.
Both servers have 8 cores, 32 GB RAM and SSD storage.

Running queries using multiple "query_string" queries is very fast (max. 0.5 sec), but once I use a "fuzzy_like_this" query, some queries take up to 30 seconds.
The queries look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "from": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "fuzzy_like_this": {
                  "boost": 1,
                  "analyzer": "german",
                  "min_similarity": 0.5,
                  "like_text": "Playstation",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "ignore_tf": false,
                  "max_query_terms": 5
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "Playstation",
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "analyzer": "german"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

Is it possible to speed this up?

Comment: An option might be to do the document analysis (german analyzer) when you index your documents to elasticsearch search, not at query time. This might increase the size of the index, but improve query performance. Also try to increase the heap size of ES to 16BG, 30sec seems too much for your scenario.

Comment: I thought that the analyzer only analyzes my query. So it might not be a big performance problem. Nevertheless, I removed the analyzer, but the query still needs the same time.